# angular sublimetext2, one file works, the other don't, can't see the difference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sublimetext2

Going over the tutorial for angularjs and trying to recreate the different steps. When going over the routes we create a file app.js. My text editor is SublimeText2, both syntax are set to javascript. They containt the same code (at least to my eyes, happy to hear if you see differently). However one works, not the other. The one that works is called app2.js, the one that doesn't app.js
Here is the result of my bash: `$ diff app.js app2.js > diff.txt`

```
3a4
> 
5,7c6,8
<   'ngRoute',
<   'phonecatControllers'
<   ]);
---
>   'ngRoute',
>   'phonecatControllers'
> ]);
10,23c11,24
<   function($routeProvider) {
<       $routeProvider.
<       when('/phones', {
<       templateURL: 'partials/phone-list.html',
<       controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
<   }).
<   when('/phones/:phoneId', {
<       templateURL: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
<       controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
<   }).
<   otherwise({
<       redirectTo:'/phones'
<   });
< }]);
\ No newline at end of file
---
>   function($routeProvider) {
>     $routeProvider.
>       when('/phones', {
>         templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html',
>         controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
>       }).
>       when('/phones/:phoneId', {
>         templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
>         controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
>       }).
>       otherwise({
>         redirectTo: '/phones'
>       });
>   }]);
```

Can you help me spot the differences? Or would you have any other idea why one file works and not the other? I thought in Javascript spaces don't make a difference, not like Python?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: @Thara I don't really get an error. This file is used for routing. With app2.js, I can see my web pages, with app.js it doesn't read/load them so it displays nothing. It's this step in the tutorial: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have got the angular-route.js, and included it in your index.html  as follows,

```
<head>
...
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also ensure you have added the ng-View

```
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes I have, otherwise, when I copy and paste the code from app2.js into app.js it wouldn't work. Everything else being equal, it's this file that makes it or break it.

Comment: hm, your app.config seems alright. Ok - Did you change your index.html reference from app.js to app2.js?

Comment: I don't change the reference as I am using the same file. To see that it works with app2.js, I just copy/paste the code from app2.js and the replace then one in app.js.